# Can PyCharm type hint magic methods?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

I want to get PyCharm/IntelliJ to include the `__get__` attribute magic method when resolving attribute types.

In the example below, the name attribute of the `Foo` instance is an instance of `Name` but can also be accessed as a string through the implementation of `__get__`.

[image]

What is the correct way to type hint in the doc string? can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

I used to do the following with ordinary methods and functions and I believe that it will work with the 'magic' methods also:

```
def __get__(self, instance, owner):
   """Description.
   :type instance: str
   :param instance: description.
   :type owner: str
   :param owner: description.
   :rtype: str
   :return: description.
   """
   return 'Hello'
```

I've just put `str` for all parameters as an example; change it for suitable types.